# Laravel - pivot relationship & naming the relationships

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, pivot-table, eloquent

I have a table `'shop_visit_count'` with columns ( `'user_id`', `'shop_id'`, `'visit_count'`, `'created_at'`, `'updated_at'` ),

A `user` can have many restaurant `visit_counts`, A `restaurant` can have many different user `visit_counts` of the same restaurant

the `visit_count` will be updated everytime the user visits a restaurant

Should I convert this to a `pivot table`?, or Should I add/keep the incremental Id `primary key` field?

If I need to convert to a `pivot table`, what should I name this `many-to-many` relationship? since this is not like the usual `'user'`, `'shop'`, `'shop_user'` type relationship, but about the `visit_count`?

Comment: Isnt `shop_visit_count` already a pivot table?

Comment: I believe it fits the pivot table rules, but I am not sure what to name the many-to-many relationship functions in both the 'User' and 'Shop' table, should I call it 'ShopVisitCounts()' (User) and 'UserVisitCounts()'?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the table "shop_visit_count", it is ok. Pivot Tables don't bring much more.

Have you troubles with that actual table ?

Comment: I see, I removed the Incrementing Id Primary Key from the table because I am trying to convert my tables to pivot table if possible, are you suggesting I should keep the Id Primary Column + the Model, and not convert the table into a pivot table?

Comment: Actually, youre current table match the pivot patern